# На чем происходит вызов?

Tags: javascript, методы, прототипное-наследование, объекты

Я не совсем понимаю как правильно говорить. Например, в первом случае вызов метода value() на функции-конструкторе или на встроенном объекте Object?

```
let obj = { num1: 1, num2: 2, num3: 3 };
let values = Object.values(obj); //на чем происходит вызов?
```

Здесь вызов происходит на самом массиве?

```
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4]; 
let iteratorValues = arr.values(); //?
```

А в чем вообще разница между 1-ым и 2-ым? Насколько я знаю, прототип, который есть у встроенной функции-конструктора - т.е. встроенный прототип, есть и у обычного объекта, который был создан этой функцией-конструкцией. Ну то есть если какой-то прототип есть у `Object` (встроенная функция-конструктор), то впоследствии этот прототип также будет и у того объекта, который этой функцией `Object` создается. То есть я имею в виду почему я не могу вызвать напрямую `obj.values()`? Ведь по идее, если этот метод есть у `Object`, то он должен быть и у `obj`.

Или `values()` находится не в прототипах, а в самом объекте `Object`?

Comment: _А в чем вообще разница между 1-ым и 2-ым?_ - разница в том. что вызываются **разные методы**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю понятнее будет на примерах показать

В первом случае мы вызываем статический метод. В моём примере это метод `getAsObj`. Такого метода нет у переменной `myMap`, т.е. нет у экземпляра, потому в консоли мы увидим ошибку. Если метод статический, то его надо вызывать так `НазваниеКласса.имяСтатическойФункции`. Ни статические методы, ни статические свойства не могут быть вызваны для экземпляров класса. Вместо этого они вызываются в самом классе. Потому я могу спокойно вызывать `getAsObj` у класса `MyMap`

```js
class MyMap {
  map;
  
  static getAsObj(x) {
    const obj = {};
    
    for(const [key, value] of x) obj[key] = value;
    
    return obj;
  }
  
  constructor() {
    this.map = new Map();
  }  
}

const myMap = new MyMap();
myMap.map.set(1, 2);
myMap.map.set(3, 4);
myMap.map.set(5, 6);

try {
  console.log(myMap.getAsObj(myMap.map));
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e.message);
}

console.log(MyMap.getAsObj(myMap.map));
```

Во втором случае мы вызываем обычный метод. В моём примере это метод `getAsObj`, который спокойно могу вызывать у экземпляра класса. Но зато теперь я не могу вызывать `getAsObj` у самого класса, потому мы увидим ошибку в консоли

```js
class MyMap {
  map;
  
  getAsObj() {
    const obj = {};
    
    for(const [key, value] of this.map) {
      obj[key] = value;
    }
    
    return obj;
  }
  
  constructor() {
    this.map = new Map();
  }  
}

const myMap = new MyMap();
myMap.map.set(1, 2);
myMap.map.set(3, 4);
myMap.map.set(5, 6);

try {
  console.log(MyMap.getAsObj());
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e.message);
}

console.log(myMap.getAsObj());
```